# Rails: Auth Token in Full, Non-API App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, access-token

I'm building a rails app and I want to have token authentication but I don't want to build a separate API, I want it to be all integrated into one rails app.

Is this possible? Every single tutorial about token authentication I can find is about APIs, and every API seems to need to be its own standalone entity running in parallel with the main app.

Is what I'm asking impossible, or stupid? If not, how do I do it?

Comment: What tutorials are you looking at? After a quick search for "rails app token auth api controller", I'm seeing that most tutorials have you set up a new app, but this is just for demo purposes. This looks like a pretty good one, that assumes you're adding token auth to an existing app: http://www.mccartie.com/2016/11/03/token-based-api-authentication.html

Comment: @max makes a good point. I assumed you were trying to authenticate an API within an existing app, not that you were trying to authenticate a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "classical" web applications you want to use session based authentication instead of tokens.

Token based authentication is stateless and requires the token to be sent along with every request. This is done via HTTP headers or by placing it in the request body. Which is how you use API's.

For a classical web application there is simply no practical way to send the token along on GET requests.

Session based authentication instead works by using cookies to store the authentication claim (usually a user id). While you could use a token and store it in the session its just an overly convoluted solution since it defeats the whole purpose of token based auth.

Comment: There are different javascript based solutions to using token based auth in classical applications but really why bother?